# Python sum numbers in 2x for loops with if condition

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, sum

I want to add values 'm' to a sum 'k' until the date changes. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to reset 'k' to zero appropriately. Right now it sums up all numbers in the list. If I put 'k = 0' into the for loop, only the last difference of a day are added.
A value of the dictionary consists of a list of lists.
Thanks in advance. Hope I explained it clearly.

```
a = defaultdict()
for key, value in dictionary3.items():

    k = 0

    for j in range(1,len(value)):
        #k = 0
        if value[j-1][0].day == value[j][0].day:
            m = value[j][1] - value[j-1][1]
            k = k + m
    a[key] = [value[j-1][0], k]
```

Output:

('A002', 'R051', '02-03-01', '59 ST') [datetime.date(2017, 3, 25), 219655]
 54

('A002', 'R051', '02-03-01', '59 ST') [datetime.date(2017, 3, 25), 219672] 
71

('A002', 'R051', '02-03-01', '59 ST') [datetime.date(2017, 3, 25), 219766] 
165

('A002', 'R051', '02-03-01', '59 ST') [datetime.date(2017, 3, 25), 220060] 
459

('A002', 'R051', '02-03-01', '59 ST') [datetime.date(2017, 3, 25), 220341] 740

('A002', 'R051', '02-03-01', '59 ST') [datetime.date(2017, 3, 26), 220555] 740

('A002', 'R051', '02-03-01', '59 ST') [datetime.date(2017, 3, 26), 220619] 804

('A002', 'R051', '02-03-01', '59 ST') [datetime.date(2017, 3, 26), 220636] 821

('A002', 'R051', '02-03-01', '59 ST') [datetime.date(2017, 3, 26), 220710] 895

Update -> dictionary:

```
{('A030', 'R083', '01-00-01', '23 ST'): [[datetime.date(2017, 3, 31), 5890208],
                                     [datetime.date(2017, 3, 31), 5890421],
                                     [datetime.date(2017, 3, 31), 5890694],
                                     [datetime.date(2017, 3, 31), 5891310]],
```

Comment: Can you post the input dictionary here?

Comment: The question might be clearer if you show a corresponding example of the output you were hoping for.

Comment: Seeing the dictionary3 would help. Is the Output you posted the expected output? or the actual / wrong output you're getting?

Comment: `if value[j-1][0].day != value[j][0].day: k = 0` or just `else:` clause on the condition.

Comment: An `else` clause would be the appropriate place to set `k=0` but that clause would also need to contain logic that stores the old value of `k` and associates it with the date.  That same logic would also need to be triggered when the end of the list is reached.

Comment: @JacobIRR updated it

Comment: ok, so when I run your code with that example, I get this value for `a` : `{('A030', 'R083', '01-00-01', '23 ST'): [datetime.date(2017, 3, 31), 1102]}` - what *should* this value be based on your description? @Skrai2004

Comment: @JacobIRR that's correct. I just recognized that only the last date + count is assigned to the key ( a[key] = [value[j-1][0], k] ) because after a value is done it gets overwritten and not appended. I haven't figured out how to do it with append.